# Python: Extract 2nd level from json to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have what I thought was simple json in this format, but I only need the "rows" field as a pandas dataframe:

```
{    "data":{
      "filters":null,
      "records":{
         "totalrecords":3031,
         "limit":3031,
         "offset":0,
         "data":{
            "headers":{
               "symbol":"SYMBOL",
               "companyName":"NAME",
               "lastSalePrice":"LAST PRICE",
               "percentageChange":"% CHANGE",
               "oneYearPercentagechange":"1 yr % CHANGE"
            },
            "rows":[
               {
                  "oneYearPercentage":"11.20%",
                  "symbol":"KSCD",
                  "companyName":"KFA Small Cap Quality Dividend Index ETF",
                  "lastSalePrice":"$27.9998",
                  "netChange":"+0.4788",
                  "percentageChange":"1.74%",
                  "deltaIndicator":"up"
               },
               {
                  "oneYearPercentage":"58.70%",
                  "symbol":"KURE",
                  "companyName":"KraneShares MSCI All China Health Care Index ETF",
                  "lastSalePrice":"$41.62",
                  "netChange":"+1.47",
                  "percentageChange":"3.66%",
                  "deltaIndicator":"up"
               }
            ]
         }
      }    } }
```

How can I parse only the "rows" field into a Pandas Dataframe, I've tried something like this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json


with open('etf-data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
print(data['data']['rows'])    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(data), orient='columns')
```

But I'm not sure how many levels deep I have to go to parse the fields here properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Figured it out after I saw the JSON again here. My solution is as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json


with open('etf-data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
print(data['data']['records']['data']['rows'])    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['data']['records']['data']['rows'], orient='columns')
df.head()
```

Which gives the output of:

|  | oneYearPercentage |  | symbol | companyName | lastSalePrice | netChange | percentageChange | deltaIndicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 11.20% |  | KSCD | KFA Small Cap Quality Dividend Index ETF | $27.9998 | +0.4788 | 1.74% | up |
|  | 58.70% |  | KURE | KraneShares MSCI All China Health Care Index ETF | $41.62 | +1.47 | 3.66% | up |
|  | 79.47% |  | KWEB | KraneShares Trust KraneShares CSI China Intern... | $93.47 | +3.68 | 4.1% | up |
|  | 11.37% |  | KWT | iShares Trust | $28.4598 | +0.4698 | 1.68% | up |
|  | 2.26% |  | KXI | iShares Global Consumer Staples ETF | $54.97 | +0.56 | 1.03% | up |

Answer (score 0):

Try with recursive call for key search function

```
def findrows(js, key):
         for k, v  in js.items():
             if k == key:
                 return v
             elif isinstance(v, dict):
                 found = findrows(v, key) 
                 if found is not None: 
                     return found
                 
pd.DataFrame(findrows(js,'rows'))
Out[179]: 
  oneYearPercentage symbol  ... percentageChange deltaIndicator
0            11.20%   KSCD  ...            1.74%             up
1            58.70%   KURE  ...            3.66%             up
[2 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

For nested json such as this, I would suggest using [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/); it can abstract some of the indexing with a *cleaner* look :

```
import jmespath
expression = jmespath.compile("data.records.data.rows")
# data is the variable name containing the json data
pd.DataFrame(expression.search(data))

  oneYearPercentage symbol                                       companyName lastSalePrice netChange percentageChange deltaIndicator
0            11.20%   KSCD          KFA Small Cap Quality Dividend Index ETF      $27.9998   +0.4788            1.74%             up
1            58.70%   KURE  KraneShares MSCI All China Health Care Index ETF        $41.62     +1.47            3.66%             up
```